# Let's encrypt Raspberry Pi stretch not working

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, lets-encrypt

I have a Raspberry Pi running the default apache webserver. I have configured DuckDNS at my domain `example.duckdns.org` (not the real domain). My `000-default.conf` apache configuration is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.duckdns.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Visiting example.duckdns.org in my browser correctly shows the default apache page ("It works!"). Now I want to use letsencrypt to securely access my site.

I tried to enable the Stretch backports repo but that didn't work: `apt update` doesn't work because the repo is not signed and I can't get it to sign. So I installed the `python-certbot-apache` from the main repo and not from the backport repo, but I dont think that should make any difference.

Running `sudo cerbot --apache` produces the following two configuration files:

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.duckdns.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.duckdns.org
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

000-default-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.duckdns.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.duckdns.org/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.duckdns.org/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Now however if I try to navigate to my site at `example.duckdns.org`, my browser correctly redirects to `https://example.duckdns.org`, but then nothing happens at all: the browser displays a timeout. I tried restarting the Raspberry Pi, reloading and restarting apache and redoing the whole process over.

What did I do wrong? This is the most simple example I could think of, and it still isn't working. Is it because of the Raspberry Pi (model 3)?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, embarrassing mistake. I forgot to port forward the SSL port 443. Maybe that's informative for future readers, so I'll post it here.